# Git commit --amend replace word in message script

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to write a bash script that runs

```
git commit --amend
```

and my default editor is Vim. In the commit message I want to replace

```
Reviewed: notreviewed
```

to

```
Reviewed: $myarg
```

How does one do this with a script?

Comment: Are you intending to provide a git hash as a parameter to the script?  And also the `$myarg` variable?

Comment: I want to call the script like "./myscript.sh myarg"

Comment: So then it will automatically apply to the most recent commit?

Comment: @TnHn: You don't need a script for this just a replacement command directly on the `vi` command line, refer my answer below!

Comment: @Inian I want to run git commit --amend too and replace in one command. Don't I need a script for that?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't the best option (it relies on `myarg` not containing any `/` characters, or anything that could terminate the `sed` command prematurely), but a single `filter-branch` command can be used in place of `git commit --amend`.

```
git filter-branch --msg-filter "sed '/Reviewed:/s/notreviewed/$myarg/'" HEAD
```

Comment: You could however choose another arbitrary character that the myarg must (or will most likely) not contain `"sed '/Reviewed:/s§notreviewed§$myarg§'"`

Comment: It's not just that. If `myArg="This isn't cool"`, then the single quote will terminate the argument to `sed` prematurely. You need to be very careful about building commands like this dynamically.